# How do you map multiple error codes to one page in Spring?

Tags: spring, error-handling

**web xml**

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/support/error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>

  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/support/error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>

  <error-page>
    <error-code>405</error-code>
    <location>/support/error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>

  <error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/support/error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>


  <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/support/error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>

   <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/support/error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
```

**I'm trying to map all exceptions and errors to one page (error.jsp). If this is possible can I configure spring like this?**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using [`SimpleMappingExceptionResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/portlet/handler/SimpleMappingExceptionResolver.html).  You can view it as a `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` for `Exception`'s.  Here is a [blogpost](http://developingdeveloper.wordpress.com/2008/02/20/handling-exceptions-in-spring-mvc-part-1/) that talks more about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.lang.Exception">serviceFault</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="defaultErrorView" value="serviceFault" />
</bean>
```